# Test Case pass while running in eclipse with Junit but fails with mvn install

Tags: spring, junit, junit-jupiter

When i run the testcase with Junit it passes but failing with mvn install.

assertEquals(2, flight.getDelayCodes().getLocal().size());

[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   FlightEventHandlerTest.testDelayCodesUpdateFields:302 expected:<2> but was:<0>

I tried by adding junit dependecny, still same error
tried with surefire plugin still same error

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                    <forkCount>4</forkCount>
                    <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <runOrder>failedfirst</runOrder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of debugging, building  the dependency projects again made trick.Worked for me.